# error: Unknown application extension '.' - expected '.app' or '.ipa'

Tags: ios, xcode

my Xcode build fails during the "Validate" phase with the following error

```
unknown application extension '.: expected '.app' or '.ipa'
```

Comment: If you've found a solution by yourself, please post an answer for your question, don't place your solution inside the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution if someones runs on this too :

- Open your project configuration, go to 'Build Settings' > 'Packaging' > 'Wrapper Extension'
- Edit the value : should be "app"

This will re-generate the "BuildableName" value in your .xcscheme files.